# Thread OnTerminate

Tags: multithreading, winapi, memory, pointers

I am working on kind of a download manager that's Multithreaded.
Each Thread has it's own ID/Handles/URL/etc.

I would to implement something like Pause/Resume/Cancel a download.
I have the ThreadHandles stored in a listview so I could Suspend/Resume/Terminate the download Threads. I haven't tried Suspend/Resume yet because I am currently working on cancel a download. The only problem is if I suspend a thread, the FileHandles/DLHandles get not closed.
Since the handles are stacked in the thread. Is there a possibility to get the pointer that I passed for CreateThread?

How I create Threads

```
type
 PTR_Download = ^TTDownload;
 TTDownload = record
 URL: string;
 ThreadHandle : Longword;
 // .....
end;

function DownloadFile ( p : pointer ) : Integer; stdcall; // The Thread
var
 _infos: TTDownload;
begin
 CopyMemory(@_infos, p, SizeOf(_infos));
 DownloadFile (_infos.URL); // just example
 // .... and so on
 // .... Handles get created here FileHandle/InternetOpenHandle/etc..
end;

function StartNewDownload (Link : String)
var
 DL : PTR_Download;
 ThreadID : DWORD;
begin
 DL := PTR_Download(LocalAlloc(LPTR, SizeOf(TTDownload)));
 DL^.URL := Link;
 DL.ThreadHandle := CreateThread(nil, 0, @DownloadFile, DL, 0, ThreadID);
end;

function AnotherFunction (dummy : String) : Bool;
begin
 GetParameterPointerOfThreadHandle (AnyHandleHere) // Something like that?!
end;
```

I basically need just something that closes the open handles from the terminated threads.
Any Ideas?

Comment: Please add a tag for the language you're using.

Comment: Looks like old non-OO Pascal - Delphi with all the good stuff taken out :(

Comment: Do you have exception support - if you close the open HTTP client socket handle from another thread, what happens?  What happens if it is closed already?

Comment: I can't close the handles from another thread cause they're handles are stacked in the thread. If the thread gets terminated, all Handles will be gone.

Comment: ..if you are going to stop the download, you are going to have to save.. something to make the thread/sockets/whatever accessible.  In an OO language, DL would be a class and saved on a list or vector.  You need to do something similar with your DL ponter - keep it in a dynamic array, or the like.  You cannot fire-and-forget your DL's if  you want to reference them later to stop them.